# Why does the division return the wrong remainder?

Tags: function, if-statement, vbscript

This is a simple piece of code in VBScript, but it is not showing the expected output. It shows the value `1` twice. It should show `3` as the remainder is three. Do I need to define a new variable in order to show an accurate result?

```
Dim a, b, c, d

a = 5
b = 2
c = division(a, b)
MsgBox "The division is zero" & " " & c
d = division(a, b)
MsgBox "The division is not zero" & " " & d

Function division(a,b)
  Dim Varinfn
  Varinfn = a Mod b
  If Varinfn = 0 Then
    division = Varinfn
  Else
    division = Varinfn
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: You have two Msgbox. Why should this code display your text three times?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten: No, it's not displaying the result three times. I need to display the correct result. I used message box twice to show the correct answer. Maybe I should make it in a way such that it will ignore the wrong one.

Answer (score 2):

The result of 5 Mod 2 is 1, because 5 - (2 * 2) = 1. So your script displays what's right.